# Using of tasks in openmp for recursive calls

Tags: c, openmp, parallel-processing

This is sample program using openmp tasks. In the specs it mentioned that as we encounter a task in a parallel region it will assigned to a thread.

Now I was not able to figure out what happens in this scenario. In each recursive call a task is being created. Each task will have it own stack space and will be destroyed when the task is completed. Can you explain how the values in the recursive calls are preseved even though the variables are shared ?

```
#include "stdio.h"

int com_fib(int n)
{
int f,fn2,fn1;
// f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
if(n == 0||n == 1) return n;
if ( n < 20 ) return(com_fib(n-1) + com_fib(n-2));

#pragma omp task shared(fn1)
{ fn1 = com_fib(n-1); }

#pragma omp task shared(fn2)
{ fn2 = com_fib(n-2); }

#pragma omp taskwait
f = fn1 + fn1;

return f;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int result;
// printf("arg is %d\n", atoi(argv[1]) );
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single nowait
    {
        result = com_fib(atoi(argv[1]));
    } // End of single
} // End of parallel region
printf("Fib is %d\n", result);

}
```

Comment: to be more specific in sequential execution every thing is preserved in stack. But here the stack gets destroyed after task completion

Comment: This question is addressed at http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1385&p=5392#p5392. Considering the question is identical i assume one of these is a repost.